# jQuery to increase quantity and total price for multiple items

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to get my jQuery code to increase/decrease  the quantity and compute the total price for each item. The problem is, when i press the quantity increase/decrease button for a single item, all quantity fields, for all items in the cart updated to the same value. total price is only given for the first item.

[cart image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofOf2.png)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".item").on("input", ".quantity", function() {
        var price = +$(".price").data("price");
        var quantity = +$(this).val();
        $("#total").text("$" + price * quantity);
    })

    var $buttonPlus = $('.btn-plus');
    var $buttonMin = $('.btn-minus');
    var $quantity = $('.quantity');

    /*For plus and minus buttons*/
    $buttonPlus.click(function() {
        $quantity.val(Math.min(parseInt($quantity.val()) + 1, 999)).trigger('input');
    });

    $buttonMin.click(function() {
        $quantity.val(Math.max(parseInt($quantity.val()) - 1, 1)).trigger('input');
    });
});
```

```
<?php
function shoppingcartelement($productimg,$productname,$price,$productid){
$element="
<form action=\"cart.php?action=remove&id=$productid\" method=\"post\" class=\"cart-items\">
    <div class=\"item border rounded\">
        <div class=\"row\">
            <div class=\"col-md-3\">
                <img src=\"$productimg\" alt=\"img1\" class=\"img-fluid\">
            </div>
            <div class=\"col-md-2 bg-white\">
                <h5 class=\"pt-2\">$productname</h5>
                <p id=\"$productid\"></p>
                <h5 class=\"price pt-2\" data-price=\"$price\">$ $price</h5>
            </div>
            <div class=\"col-md-3 py-5 bg-white\">
                <div class=\"input-group\">
                    <span class=\"input-group-btn\">
                        <button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-info btn-minus\" data-type=\"minus\" data-field=\"quant[1]\">
                            <img style=\"height:15px\" width=\"15px\" src=\"./icon/minus.png\" alt=\"\">
                        </button>
                    </span>
                    <input type=\"text\" class=\"quantity form-control mx-1\" value=\"1\">
                    <span class=\"input-group-btn\">
                        <button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-info btn-plus\" data-type=\"plus\" data-field=\"quant[1]\">
                            <img style=\"height:15px\" width=\"15px\" src=\"./icon/plus.png\" alt=\"\">
                        </button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class=\"col-md-3 bg-white\">
                <h5 class=\"total my-5\">Total: <span id=\"total\">$ $price</span></h5>
            </div>
            <div class=\"col-md-1 bg-white\">
                <button type=\"submit\" class=\"bg-white mt-5\" style=\"border: none; outline:none;\" name=\"remove\">
                    <img style=\"height:30px\" width=\"30px\" src=\"./icon/x.png\" alt=\"\">
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
";
echo $element;
}
```

Comment: IDs must be unique within an HTML document.

Comment: How do i achieve that. the data on that PHP file is fetched from my database.

Comment: Well you could for example append your product ID as a suffix to `id="total"`. But then your JS part would have to handle all those different IDs accordingly as well. The better way to go about this would be to use a class instead of id, and find the correct span element to update based on its relation to the trigger buttons in the DOM.

Comment: do you have any live example?

Answer (score 1):

Your click handler is looking at $quantity which is returning all of the quantity input fields not just the one corresponding the the button being clicked. 
Try something like this:

```
$buttonPlus.click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.input-group').find('.quantity').val(Math.min(parseInt($quantity.val()) + 1, 999)).trigger('input');
});
```

In this example you're looking for the wrapping input group container and getting the input field from that specific container.

Comment: Assuming you're looping through items when you build out the DOM, the simplest route would likely be to increment the ids with a count variable. For example if your product id is '12345', then something like '12345_1' where 1 is the first product in the cart. Without seeing how you're building that out though, a different strategy could make more sense.